# How can I get a list of childnodes checked in a treeview vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, webforms, treeview

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Design view for my treeview:

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" ShowExpandCollapse="true" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="Leaf"
            ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        </asp:TreeView>
```

The code:

```
Private Sub MyProject_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

     ' MY DATATABLE WITH THE VALUES:
        Dim dt as datatable = mymethodtoreadvaluesfrombd()
       TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
            Dim node As TreeNode
            Dim subNode As TreeNode
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

                node = Searchnode(row.Item(2).ToString(), TreeView1)
                If node IsNot Nothing Then

                    subNode = New TreeNode(row.Item(3).ToString())

                    subNode.ShowCheckBox = True
                    node.ChildNodes.Add(subNode)
                Else
                    node = New TreeNode(row.Item(2).ToString())
                    subNode = New TreeNode(row.Item(3).ToString())

                    node.ChildNodes.Add(subNode)
                    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node)
                End If
            Next
End Sub

 Private Function Searchnode(ByVal nodetext As String, ByVal trv As TreeView) As TreeNode
        For Each node As TreeNode In trv.Nodes
            If node.Text = nodetext Then
                Return node
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

I have a button and when I click it I need to read the childnodes checked y my treeview.
I can´t find the way I tried many codes, can anyone suggests me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a second `for...each` loop to loop through the child nodes:

```
For Each Parentnode as TreeNode in TreeVeiw1.Nodes
    For Each Childnode as Treenode in Parentnode.Nodes
        If Childnode.checked Then

        End If
    Next
Next
```

My suggestion for the ID (see comment below) would be to use `Childnode.Tag`, most controls include `.Tag` in which you can store data.

Comment: And how can I get the checked childnodes from treeview?, thanks

Comment: I have another question, when I create the treeview I assign the text value for the child node, so when I get the list for the checked elements I obtein the text name from the childnode, my question is, how can I save also the ID into a childnode, to save after the changes into the database? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in my code,

the problem was that when I click the button there are an autopostback event wich makes the treeview checkboxes deleted, so i put this in the load, to go directly to the button action click:

```
Private Sub MyProject_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

If not is postback then

' create the treeview

end if

End Sub
```